# Cant make a Css-Menu

Tags: css, menu

How do i do a navigation menu in CSS? I want a menu with 4 menu buttons! Been searching google and asking friends but hasen't been able to figure something out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did any of the below answers help you? If so could you accept an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please read the first answer on this question before posting again. It will help you understand what SO is here for:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/k3AbH/1/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}

ul li a {
    padding:6px 10px;
    border-right:1px solic #C0C0C0;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#A1A1A1;
    display:block;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

ul li > ul { display: none; }
ul li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```